# Hibernate expecting wrong parameter type in HQL

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hql

We have an hierarchy of entities, e.g. abstract Basket and two concrete, which in turn can contain a list of some other items, for example, with exact same hierarchy(SaleBasketItem, ReturnBasketItem).

```
@Entity
@XStreamAlias("basket")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "basket_type")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Basket<T extends BasketItem> 

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "SALE")
public class SaleBasket extends Basket<SaleBasketItem> 

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "RETURN")
public class ReturnBasket extends Basket<ReturnBasketItem> 

@Entity
@Table(name = "basket_item")
@XStreamAlias("basket_str")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "basket_item_type")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class BasketItem<U extends BasketItem, V extends Basket>

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "RETURN")
public class ReturnBasketItem extends BasketItem<ReturnBasketItem, ReturnBasket>


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "SALE")
public class SaleBasketItem extends BasketItem<SaleBasketItem, SaleBasket>
```

So, the problem arises when I try to execute hql query like

```
"SELECT bi FROM " + basketType + "BasketItem bi JOIN bi.basket b JOIN b.saleSession JOIN bi.ware w WHERE b.state = :state"
```

where `basketType` is dynamically either "Sale" or "Return". Then I put that query in `TypedQuery` with type of `BasketItem` I need and try to `setParameter("state", state)`, where `state` is some enum representing state of concrete basket (different in each concrete class, not present in abstract class at all), which throws

> IllegalArgumentException(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value ... was not matching type)

where type is `ReturnBasketState` when actual is `SaleBasket` state, or vice versa.

So the question is - how to force Hibernate to expect correct type for that parameter?

Comment: Do you pass the enum as parameter? Or a String representation of that enum value?

Comment: I passed Enum as param

Answer (score -1):

I suppose it's expecting a String as parameter, rather than an Enum. try passing a String instead.

Comment: No, it's expecting other enum. It's trying to infer type of bi.basket, but fails at that.